# How to know when service is started after calling startService() method to send otto event?

Tags: android, service, otto

I have AlarmReceiver(`BrodcastReceiver`) that starts DownloadService(`Service`) after check if service is not running state

```
context.startDownloadServiceIfNotRunning()// kotlin extension function check service state
```

after this line i am sending [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)  event to previously started service

```
BusStation.getBus().post(DownloadEvent())  // Actually this line fired before start of service
```

but download service is not receiving this event even it is registerd for event.

**after Debugging i have found that  Otto event is firing before service actually starts therefore it is not receiving any event**

so is there any way to know when android Service is Started properly to Receive events by otto

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter to intent. How about use parameters, not the Otto?

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,DownloadService.class); 
serviceIntent.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

and, onStart of service, you can use parameters.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(extras == null) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        String value = (String) extras.get("Key");
        if (value.equals("Value")) {
            // Do same thing you want to do with Otto event.
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited:**
If your event is not a time-critical one, you can simply delay your event.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        BusStation.getBus().post(DownloadEvent());
    }
},1000);
```

Otherwise, you need to make your own message queue.

Comment: but also when  app is running onStart of app i am starting this service in background after that in between i send otto events to DownloadService. so in onStart i don't have any value to pass in intent so how to handle this case